# Saving data to persist on update (Unity3D)

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

I am about to publish my first Unity3d app on the standard android and ios app stores. I want to save the user data file in a directory on the device so that users can download the future updates and have the data persist on their phone (i.e. so that the new updated program can access data left over from before). Which would be the correct directories to write the data file on ios/android?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Unity's persistent data path, via the [Application class](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html):

```
string filePath = Application.persistentDataPath;
```

You might need to [clean up the path](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/18647/unity-iphone-can-i-store-data-on-the-iphone-to-be.html) slightly depending on the device's particular read/write access to the data folder.

And for any that want a simpler method, [Unity's PlayerPrefs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) will handle storing session data, provided all you want to save are simple numerical values or strings.